# Spring Data MongoDB @CreatedDate using Java 8 LocaDate Converter

Tags: java-8, spring-data-mongodb

I wan't to use java.util.LocalDate in my domain class that get persisted to MongoDB using Spring Data.

My domain classes has this as parent :-

```
public abstract class AuditableMongoEntity extends VersionAwareMongoEntity {

    /**
     * serialVersionUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -67203638183725497L;

    @CreatedDate
    protected LocalDate dateCreated;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @JsonIgnore
    protected LocalDate lastUpdated;
}
```

My requirements:-

- 'dateCreated' field should be saved as no. of days passed since epoch. My business does not need millisecs level of details and does not require hour/minute/sec infromation.
- I also want to persist 'year','month','week' along with days for the dateCreated field and enable indexing on them.

For the first requirement I can register a custom `Converter<LocalDate, Long>`.

How should implement the second requirement?

Spring Boot version 1.3.x